FlutterMethodChannel Data Passing Issue
Hi all this is how I used to render the flutter content in my iOS Application. unfortunately data is not getting send through the FlutterMethodChannel.
class HeatmapVC: UIViewController {

    lazy var flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "heatmap_engine")
    var methodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel?
    var flutterViewController: FlutterViewController?

    @IBOutlet var heatmapView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Run the engine and register plugins
        flutterEngine.run()
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: flutterEngine) // Register plugins here

        flutterViewController = FlutterViewController(engine: flutterEngine, nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        // Add FlutterViewController as a child view controller
        if let flutterVC = flutterViewController {
            addChild(flutterVC)
            flutterVC.view.frame = heatmapView.bounds
            flutterVC.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            heatmapView.addSubview(flutterVC.view)
            flutterVC.didMove(toParent: self)
            
            // Set up the method channel after the view controller is added
            methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.b.heatmap/data", binaryMessenger: flutterVC.binaryMessenger)
            
            // Send data to Flutter
            self.sendDataToFlutter()
        }
    }
    
    func sendDataToFlutter() {
        let dataToSend: [[String: Any]] = [
            ["country": "India", "socialMedia": "Facebook", "usersInMillions": 25.4],
            ["country": "USA", "socialMedia": "Instagram", "usersInMillions": 19.11],
            ["country": "Japan", "socialMedia": "Facebook", "usersInMillions": 13.3],
            ["country": "Germany", "socialMedia": "Instagram", "usersInMillions": 10.65],
            ["country": "France", "socialMedia": "Twitter", "usersInMillions": 7.54],
            ["country": "UK", "socialMedia": "Instagram", "usersInMillions": 4.93]
        ]
        
        methodChannel?.invokeMethod("sendData", arguments: dataToSend) { (result: Any?) in
            if let response = result as? String {
                
                print("Flutter Response: \(response)")
            }
        }
    }


Below is the error I'm facing.

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method sendData on channel com.b.heatmap/data)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)

#1      _SocialMediaUsersTreemapState._fetchDataFromNative (package:heatmap_b/main.dart:45:36)


Looking for a solution.
Below is the flutter code I have used.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart'; // For MethodChannel
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_treemap/treemap.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: SocialMediaUsersTreemap(),
    );
  }
}

class SocialMediaUsersTreemap extends StatefulWidget {
  const SocialMediaUsersTreemap({super.key});

  @override
  // ignore: library_private_types_in_public_api
  _SocialMediaUsersTreemapState createState() => _SocialMediaUsersTreemapState();
}

class _SocialMediaUsersTreemapState extends State<SocialMediaUsersTreemap> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('com.b.heatmap/data');
  late List<SocialMediaUsers> _source;
  bool _isLoading = true; // To manage loading state

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Initialize with an empty list until data is received
    _source = <SocialMediaUsers>[];

    // Fetch data from native side
    _fetchDataFromNative();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchDataFromNative() async {
    try {
      // Call the method and await the response
      final List<dynamic> result = await platform.invokeMethod('sendData');

      // Debugging to see if data is received
      print("Data received from native: $result");

      // Process the received data and map it to the SocialMediaUsers list
      setState(() {
        _source = result.map((item) {
          return SocialMediaUsers(
            item['country'],
            item['socialMedia'],
            item['usersInMillions'].toDouble(),
          );
        }).toList();
        _isLoading = false; // Data is loaded
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print("Failed to receive data: '${e.message}'.");
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false; // End loading even on error
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Social Media Users Treemap')),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()) // Show loading spinner
          : _source.isNotEmpty
              ? SfTreemap(
                  dataCount: _source.length,
                  weightValueMapper: (int index) {
                    return _source[index].usersInMillions;
                  },
                  levels: [
                    TreemapLevel(
                      groupMapper: (int index) {
                        return _source[index].country;
                      },
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2),
                      labelBuilder: (BuildContext context, TreemapTile tile) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          child: Text(
                            '${tile.group}\n(${tile.weight.toStringAsFixed(2)}M)',
                            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              : const Center(
                  child: Text('No data available'), // Show if no data is received
                ),
    );
  }
}

class SocialMediaUsers {
  const SocialMediaUsers(this.country, this.socialMedia, this.usersInMillions);

  final String country;
  final String socialMedia;
  final double usersInMillions;
}


You are sending data only from both HeatmapVC and flutter widget. You have not set method handler to handle when the method call happens on either side. I believe you want to call method from flutter side and send data from iOS side and receive it on flutter side. You need to create methodCallHandler on iOS side and then send data. Also, before calling runapp add this line: WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

Hi Shafran,
please check this https://medium.com/codingmountain-blog/flutter-platform-channels-6e78c2fc75dc once (what i see in your code is you are not listening the methods)
